# Prestashop with smarty_internal_templatebase

Tags: php, content-management-system, prestashop

**PrestaShop 1.6.1.10**

**PHP 5.5.7**

When I turn on debugging in PrestaShop, appear as errors like this, I would fix it, but I do not understand how to fix it.

> Notice: Undefined index: br in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 34 Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 34 Notice: Undefined index: hookPaymentShow in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 44 Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 44 Notice: Undefined index: manifestPDFFooter
>   in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 52 Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 52 Notice: Undefined index: desc in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 54 Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157)
>   : eval()'d code on line 54

Comment: Check modules that are hooked to `hookPaymentShow` in the Page `Modules > Positions` then check the tpls of those modules. Normally you would find something like this `xxx.br` or `xxx['br']` or `xxx->br`. there is also an undefined index desc which is similar..

Answer (score 0):

It means somewhere in a tpl there is a call to hookPaymentShow (for example) in an array that is not defined (doesn't exist).

Try to find the location where the notice is thrown, and you can delete the entry or use something like `{if isset($array['variable'])}$array['variable']{/if}`